# Keep data ordered in db by order number in Flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a db(sqlite) which contains firewall and policy rule definitions in it. And i need to keep each records ordered in their firewalls. My Firewall and PolicyRule models relationship is many-to-many. So i stored the rank(order number) in the association model. How can i keep them ordered even if i insert data middle of the records?

For example:

I get my records with order_by in this order:

```
1- Rule A 
2- Rule B 
3- Rule C
```

And then i want to add the Rule D between Rule B and Rule C. So my next query result must be like this:

```
1- Rule A
2- Rule B
3- Rule D
4- Rule C
```

I need to know rules exact order because of i apply them on iptables and iptables policys must be exact same order with users.

Here is my models:

```
class PolicyRule(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'policy_rule'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    active = db.Column('is_active', db.Boolean(), nullable=False, server_default='1')
    name = db.Column(db.String(255, collation='NOCASE'), nullable=False, unique=True)
    rule_type = db.Column(db.String(255, collation='NOCASE'), nullable=False) # IPv4 or IPv6
    direction = db.Column(db.Text())
    action = db.Column(db.Text())
    comment = db.Column(db.Text())
    log = db.Column(db.Boolean(), nullable=False, server_default='1')
    firewalls = db.relationship("FwPolicyRules", back_populates="rule")

    # Foreign key assignments for relationships
    src_addr_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey(Address.id, ondelete='CASCADE'))
    dst_addr_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey(Address.id, ondelete='CASCADE'))
    src_service_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey(Service.id, ondelete='CASCADE'))
    dst_service_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey(Service.id, ondelete='CASCADE'))
    interface_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey(Interface.id, ondelete='CASCADE'))
    time_profile_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey(TimeProfile.id, ondelete='CASCADE'))
    
    # Relationship definitions for access the objects directly like "policy_rule.src_addr".
    src_addr = db.relationship("Address", foreign_keys=[src_addr_id], lazy='subquery', backref=db.backref("policy_src_addr", uselist=True))
    src_port = db.relationship("Service", foreign_keys=[src_service_id], lazy='subquery',backref=db.backref("policy_src_port", uselist=True))
    dst_addr = db.relationship("Address", foreign_keys=[dst_addr_id], lazy='subquery',backref=db.backref("policy_dst_addr", uselist=True))
    dst_port = db.relationship("Service", foreign_keys=[dst_service_id], lazy='subquery',backref=db.backref("policy_dst_port", uselist=True))
    interface = db.relationship("Interface", foreign_keys=[interface_id], lazy='subquery',backref=db.backref("policy_interface", uselist=True))
    time_profile = db.relationship("TimeProfile", foreign_keys=[time_profile_id], lazy='subquery',backref=db.backref("policy_time_profile", uselist=True))


class Firewall(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'firewall'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255, collation='NOCASE'), nullable=False, unique=True)

    policy_rules = db.relationship("FwPolicyRules", back_populates="firewall", lazy='subquery', cascade="delete-orphan")
    nat_rules = db.relationship("FwNatRules", back_populates="firewall", lazy='subquery', cascade="delete-orphan")
    routing_rules = db.relationship("FwRoutingRules", back_populates="firewall", lazy='subquery', cascade="delete-orphan")

    interfaces = db.relationship('Interface', secondary=interfaces, lazy='subquery', backref=db.backref('used_firewalls', lazy=True, uselist=True))

class FwPolicyRules(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'fw_policy_rules'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    firewall_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('firewall.id', ondelete='cascade'))
    policy_rule_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('policy_rule.id', ondelete='cascade'))
    rank = db.Column(db.Integer, autoincrement=True)
    rule = db.relationship("PolicyRule", back_populates="firewalls", lazy='subquery')
    firewall = db.relationship("Firewall", back_populates="policy_rules", lazy='subquery')
```

EDIT: I think although of bunch of explanation no one was exactly understand my question. To be clear i want to many-to-many version of this:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/orderinglist.html

Comment: Not a formal answer, but the general pattern you follow with SQLite is to _not_ worry about the internal order of your data in SQL.  This is because, in general, there really _isn't_ any internal order at all.  Instead, if you want to _view_ your data in a certain order, just use an appropriate `ORDER BY` clause.  And, possibly consider tuning your query with indices which also can help the sorting step.

Comment: Perhaps your "rank" could be a float instead of an integer, so that if you need to insert a new record in between two existing records, you can set it in between their "rank" values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Finally i found the solition**

Here is the my solition with python way:

i imported the ordering list with this:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.orderinglist import ordering_list
```

and then i modified my Firewall model and added the default order_by parameter. After that **collection_class=ordering_list('rank')** parameter did the trick.

```
class Firewall(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'firewall'
id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
name = db.Column(db.String(255, collation='NOCASE'), nullable=False, unique=True)

policy_rules = db.relationship("FwPolicyRules", back_populates="firewall", lazy='subquery', cascade="save-update, merge, delete, delete-orphan", order_by="FwPolicyRules.rank" ,collection_class=ordering_list('rank'))
nat_rules = db.relationship("FwNatRules", back_populates="firewall", lazy='subquery', cascade="save-update, merge, delete, delete-orphan", order_by="FwNatRules.rank" ,collection_class=ordering_list('rank'))
routing_rules = db.relationship("FwRoutingRules", back_populates="firewall", lazy='subquery', cascade="save-update, merge, delete, delete-orphan", order_by="FwRoutingRules.rank" ,collection_class=ordering_list('rank'))

interfaces = db.relationship('Interface', secondary=interfaces, lazy='subquery', backref=db.backref('used_firewalls', lazy=True, uselist=True))
```

and then i just add new rule to firewall like this:

```
db.session.autoflush = False # This is important because of "cascade = delete-orphan" parameter. Otherwise PolicyRule will be deleted before its added.
new_rule = PolicyRule(...)
a = FwPolicyRules(rule=new_rule)
fw.policy_rules.insert(rank, a) # Alternatively you can use "fw.policy_rules.append(a)" for auto add rule to the end
db.session.autoflush = True
db.session.commit()
```

for change existing rule's order i wrote a function:

```
def change_rule_rank(rule_rank, new_rank):
    db.session.autoflush = False
    rule_assoc = fw.policy_rules.pop(rule_rank)
    a = FwPolicyRules(rule=rule_assoc.rule)
    fw.policy_rules.insert(new_rank, a)
    db.session.autoflush = True
    db.session.commit()
```

Hope it helps someone.